# Implement system like OnPlatform/OnIdiom

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to bind to a different property depending on the language of my app.
I would like to do this by **XAML** and was inspiried by `OnPlatform`/`OnIdiom`.

So I created something like `OnIdiom` but for Languages, but I have no clue how to make it accessible in any content in **XAML**.

```cs
using ThibertApp.Resources;

namespace ThibertApp.Localization
{
    public class OnLanguage<T>
    {
        T _EN;
        T _FR;
        bool _isENSet;
        bool _isFRSet;

        public T EN
        {
            get => _EN;
            set
            {
                _EN = value;
                _isENSet = true;
            }
        }

        public T FR
        {
            get => _FR;
            set
            {
                _FR = value;
                _isFRSet = true;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator T(OnLanguage<T> onLanguage)
        {
            switch (AppResources.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
            {
                default:
                case "en":
                    return onLanguage._isENSet ? onLanguage.EN : default(T);
                case "fr":
                    return onLanguage._isFRSet ? onLanguage.FR : default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:ThibertApp.Resources"
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ThibertApp.Localization;assembly=ThibertApp"
             x:Class="ThibertApp.Pages.HomePage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             IconImageSource="{Binding IconImageSource}"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             Style="{StaticResource ThibertPage}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="10">
            <Frame CornerRadius="10"
                   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ThibertGrey}">
                <Entry Placeholder="{Static s:AppResources.SearchPlaceholder}">
                    <Entry.Text>
                        <l:OnLanguage EN="{Binding TextEN}" FR="{Binding TextFR}"/>
                    </Entry.Text>
                </Entry>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When I reference my class and attempt to enter values it gives those errors.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   XLS0504 Property 'Text' does not support values of type 'OnLanguage'.   ThibertApp  HomePage.xaml   17

and

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Position 17:26. Type l:OnLanguage not found in xmlns clr-namespace:ThibertApp.Localization  ThibertApp  C:\Users\william_d\source\repos\ThibertApp\ThibertApp\ThibertApp\Pages\HomePage.xaml    17

Does anyone have any guideline as to how to make this possible? I've cloned **Xamarin.Forms** and looked for reference to `OnIdiom`/`OnPlatform` and didn't find much that could answer my questions.

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

With Deczaloth answer I was able to come up with a markup extension like this:

```
    public class OnLanguage : BindableObject, IMarkupExtension<string>
    {
        public readonly static BindableProperty ENProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EN), typeof(string), typeof(OnLanguage));
        public string EN
        {
            get => GetValue(ENProperty) as string;
            set => SetValue(ENProperty, value);
        }

        public readonly static BindableProperty FRProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FR), typeof(string), typeof(OnLanguage));
        public string FR
        {
            get => GetValue(FRProperty) as string;
            set => SetValue(FRProperty, value);
        }

        public string ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            SetBinding(BindingContextProperty, new Binding("BindingContext", source: (serviceProvider.GetService<IProvideValueTarget>() as IProvideValueTarget).TargetObject as BindableObject));
            return LanguageManager.LocalizedObject(EN, FR);
        }

        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return (this as IMarkupExtension<string>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }
    }
```

This is how I implement it in XAML:

```
                                        <Label TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryTextColor}">
                                            <Label.Text>
                                                <other:OnLanguage EN="{Binding DescriptionEN}"
                                                                  FR="{Binding DescriptionFR}"/>
                                            </Label.Text>
                                        </Label>
```

My OnLanguage BindableObject doesn't automatically get a BindingContext. I've implemented this manually but how do I make it so that the value is reprovided to the parent when the BindingContext is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to this is more like a workaround but works very well.

The difficulty was to create two bindings but only bind one to the object's property.

This is what my final MarkupExtension looks like:

```
    public class OnLanguage : BindableObject, IMarkupExtension<Binding>
    {
        public readonly static BindableProperty ENProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EN), typeof(string), typeof(OnLanguage));
        public string EN
        {
            get => GetValue(ENProperty) as string;
            set => SetValue(ENProperty, value);
        }

        public readonly static BindableProperty FRProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FR), typeof(string), typeof(OnLanguage));
        public string FR
        {
            get => GetValue(FRProperty) as string;
            set => SetValue(FRProperty, value);
        }

        public Binding ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new Binding(LanguageManager.LocalizedObject(EN, FR));
        }

        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return (this as IMarkupExtension<Binding>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        }
    }
```

And the implementation:

```
                                        <Label TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryTextColor}"
                                               x:Name="L">
                                            <Label.Text>
                                                <other:OnLanguage EN="DescriptionEN"
                                                                  FR="DescriptionFR"/>
                                            </Label.Text>
                                        </Label>
```

Because I want my MarkupExtension to provide a Binding so that the parent object can Set it to his property, but cannot have a BindableProperties of type Binding, I had to have them be strings representing the name of the property to bind. Not much different from writing {Binding DescriptionEN}. The only limitation with this solution is that it's not possible to set the source, converter, mode etc. of the Binding. If anyone has any idea of how to implement this I would be very appreciative.

I suppose I could add these as properties but that would be just rewriting all of Binding properties.

Comment: Please kindly remove the distracting whitespaces on the left.

Answer (score 3):

You might be talking about **Markup Extensions**.

You will need to make your class `OnLanguage` inherit from `IMarkupExtension` like

```cs
public class OnLanguage<T> : IMarkupExtension<T>
```

Please refer to the following Blog post:

https://xamgirl.com/xaml-markup-extension-in-xamarin-forms/